# How are data transfer costs for cross account snapshot copy, calculated?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to copy AMIs (along with the underlying snapshots) from one account to another (although both the accounts belong to the same billing account). The source and destination regions are also different.

Does this qualify as

- Data transfer across the Internet?
- Data transfer across region?

I couldn't find a definitive explanation on AWS documentation.

Looked at AWS calculator but that doesn't provide information on what qualifies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It qualifies as data transfer across regions, which costs 0.02$/GB.

This [illustration](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/open-guides/og-aws/master/figures/aws-data-transfer-costs.png) may help you understand data transfer costs, even though it is not up to date.

[image]

Comment: I realize it was implicit but just wanted to have a definitive understanding before running into a big invoice. Thank you.